How do I launch the browser while running tests in Playwright?
I'm using the Playwright example code to test my environment before I begin building out the automation framework.  Right now I'd just like to be able to watch the tests run in the actual browser.  Playwright typically provides this capability when running 'Debug'.  The tests are passing locally but I can't run in debug mode in order to actually watch the browser as the tests run.

I read documentation on the VSCODE site and adding the following configuration to my launch.json file
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:8080",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}

But when I run by clicking 'Debug' I'm getting the following error:

Can't find Node.js binary "npx": path does not exist. Make sure Node.js is installed and in your PATH, or set the "runtimeExecutable" in your launch.json

Node is indeed installed:
node --version
v21.4.0

So how exactly do I set this up to run in debug so that I can watch the browser as the end to end tests are executed?
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Probably a VSCode misconfiguration versus the node you see on your command line or npx needing to be installed.

Once I downgraded to 1.29.2 I was able to see the play icons on tests, right-click and launch the tests in headed mode.
